# Concatenating strings in mvc controller

Tags: c#, linq, linq-to-entities, string-concatenation

I've created a search controller for a name search and my code looks like this:

```
from a in _entities.MainContacts
where a.Firstname.Contains(qry) || a.Lastname.Contains(qry)
orderby a.Lastname
select a).ToList();
```

I would like to include a concatenate so that if someone puts in a fullname it will find it by looking at `firstname & " " & Lastname` I know how to create a field in sql, but not sure if its the same in mvc.

Any advice would be really gratefully received.

Cheers

ant

Comment: What do you have in your controller so far?  Where are you failing to get your controller working with your model?  It's not entirely clear what you're asking here.

Comment: Right now this appears to be a linq not MVC question - what do you believe to be different?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this.

```
where a.Firstname.Contains(qry) || a.Lastname.Contains(qry) || a.Firstname + " " + a.Lastname == qry
```

I will admit its not the best but it works and will produce sql statement like this.

```
WHERE (([t0].[Firstname] + @p0) + [t0].[Lastname]) = @p1
```

I've only included the fullname check above.

Comment: Thanks for all your comments. I will check and test this tomorrow.